# Javascript object's property saves itself and creates a weird loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object (lets say `a`), which, has a property (lets say `b`) which has a property which is its parent. Something like this :

```js
a: {
    a1 : a2,
    b  : {
        b1 : b2,
        b3 : a
    }
}
```

Which creates a weird kind of infinitely long object saving itself again and again, which I found out by using chrome's debugger.

But my question here is, despite this, the program never crashes and runs ever so smoothly, without any hanging or something, even on a laptop that is very crappy (without GPU). How is the program managing to do that?

Comment: my guess is that everything is being passed by reference -- so even though it's some crazy infinite loop, information isn't being duplicated an infinite number of times.

Comment: This is a self-referential data structure using pointers in memory.

Comment: FYI, the `window` object itself is such a self-referencing object. It's perfectly fine since it's just references, not copies, but if your program starts to iterate over the structure without any kind of self-reference check in place, you're going to have problems.

Comment: So its a cycle but it doesn't saves the information more than once.

Answer (score 1):

`a.b.b3` is a reference of `a`, not a copy, which is how Objects are passed around in JavaScript. It is an equivalent of a pointer. The fact that an object can be traversed indefinitely doesn't mean it takes up an infinite amount of memory. If you want to see that you're dealing with the same object in memory, you can do something like `a.b1 = 'something else';` and try traversing it again. The change will be reflected even as you go deep into the hierarchy, since you're going over the same Object in memory.

Comment: So that's like I am going over the same piece of memory over and over, like a cycle?